# usage of Aggregator, Group By ports

Tags: informatica-powercenter

What happens when we have a port that is a plain pass through, in an aggregator transformation(i.e with out any aggregate function). Please note that, we do have group by ports in the transformation.

I.e in SQL, it is like having a field say 'A' in the select clause with out an aggregate function, but also not added in a group by clause. but there are few field added as a part of Group by. The SQL statement would return an error when trying to execute.

How does the record behave in Informatica in such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregator will pass the value for the last record in the group if you do not use any aggregate function on the column

Comment: Thanks. I guess need to test it. I have a SQ where u order by a field and pass it to an expression with basic concatenation of field and pass to the aggregator, so based on the order by field it would basically pick the last record.